# How to set pdf page-width dynamically in pdfkit,rb (pdfkit gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

How to override `pdfkit` configuration dynamically

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/path/to/wkhtmltopdf'
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size => 'Legal',
    :print_media_type => true
:page_width=> " i just want to change this value depends on record count"====> issue
  }
```

or is it any method to set min page width and maximum page width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#usage

Create instance with params:

```
kit = PDFKit.new(html, page_width: '169.33')
```